# What's the most scalable and high performing Server/Language configuration for a Multiplayer game?

Tags: javascript, html, web-server, node.js

We're in 2017.
This question may be a duplicate of other questions asked **years ago**.
Meanwhile, new servers were born, browsers have modernized, IE6 and XP died, HTML5 appeared, servers can be written in JavaScript, SSL can be installed for free, computers have become more powerfull, mobiles replace PCs, etc, etc...
My question is quite simple:

I want to implement a few multiplayer games on my 5000+/daily active users website. Given it's 2017, how should I build my server?

The client-side will be done in HTML5 and websockets.

**What technology do you recommend for the server?**, allowing it to easily share game memory between two players, responding to events nice and softly, and yet not blow up after a few users playing concurrently...

I see BrowserQuest is made in nodeJS - https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest/tree/master/server
Only uses Memcached for metrics.

Would nodeJS be a good option? I see it is a free option and due to its nature, you can pretty much make a game match and game chat all in memory, without the need of a database, while PHP would require DB support. I'm not sure, however, how good is it as a webserver, compared to others, as I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: My first thought is that you might prefer a compiled langauge over an interpreted one. My secodn thought is that, although this question is somewhat on-topic here, it might get a better answwer on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mawg Technology recommendation is off-topic on [gamedev.se] :)

Comment: @Mawg I asked there, and it got closed as "off-topic". I also had asked in Stack Overflow and ProWebmasters, and both got closed as well. Simply, it's really hard these days to know where to ask questions in these sites. The tours are very vague and don't really explain what is the purpose of each site. There are ~5 websites where I'd say this question fits, but I'm being redirected between all of them...